# Convert 2 dimensional array to 1 dimensional array while maintaining grid order

Tags: java, arrays

I have been researching tilesets and map editing with Java. However, I have run into a problem.

The map file specifies what tiles to place as follows:

```
tileset image: tiles.png
tileset width: 1024
tileset height: 1024
tileset tile width: 16
tileset tile heigth: 16
tiles on x axis: 5
tiles on y axis: 6
tiles: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,2,2,22,3,4,26,21,9,19,28,18,2,1,1,1,1 etc...
```

The tileset image would be read as shown here:

```
                X:
     1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5
  -----------------------
  1| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
  2| 6 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 10
Y:3| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15
  4| 16| 17| 18| z | 20
  5| 21| 22| 23| 24| 25
  6| 26| 27| 28| 29| 30
```

('|'s just for spacing)

To help understand this table, the tileset **x,y coordinates** at 'z' would be **(4,4)** and its **index** would be **19**.

Now forgetting about images, as they are irrelevant here, I am wondering how I can get the index (**z's 19**) from the coordinates on the tilset (**z's (4,4)**).

e.g. If I had this code:

```
int tilesetTilesWidth = tilesetImageWidth / tileWidth;
int tilesetTilesHeight = tilesetImageHeight / tileHeight;
int[][] coords = new int[tilesetTilesWidth][tilesetTilesHeight];
int[] indexes = new int[tilesetTilesWidth * tilesetTilesHeight];

for(int x = 0; x < coords.length; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < coords[x].length; y++){
        indexes[?] = coords[x][y]; //What should ? or this line be replaced with?
    }
}
```

What should ? or this line be replaced with?

**NOTE:**
If there are any questions or anything I have missed, please drop a comment as I am in a rush.

Comment: Is the tiles on x axis: 5 rather than 6? can you correct the question or explain me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Your right. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anderson's answer is probably what you're looking for, but just to answer the question, I believe index would be `(y-1)*cords.length+x`.

Observe that in this example since cords.length = 5, y=4, and x=4, we would get (4-1)*5+4 = 3*5+4 = 15 + 4 = 19 as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a third index, `k` for example, and increment it every time you insert a new value into `indexes`:

```
for (int x = 0, k = 0; x < coords.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < coords[x].length; y++) {
        indexes[k++] = coords[x][y];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tilesetTilesWidth * tilesetTilesHeight; i++) {
    indexes[i] = coords[i%tilesetTilesWidth][i/tilesetTilesHeight];
}
```

This method uses Modular Arithmetic, and would give the same results.

NOTE: for more on modular arithmetic:

- [Rutger's Math Department](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~erowland/modulararithmetic.html)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a matrix for accessing Z(x, y).

just use Tile[(y-1)*w+x] and it will give you the element at x, y

```
tWidth = 5;
tHeight = 6; // you don't need this for accessing (x, y)

tile = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,2,2,22,3,4,26,21,9,19,....]
function get(X, Y) = tile[(Y-1)*tWidth + X];
```